# How could I craft a function that check if a word is repeated more than two time or more in a vector and output the number of time it repeated? in C++

Tags: c++

first time on Stack here, I hope to learn from you guys!
So my code involve the user reading a passage from a text-file and adding the word into a vector. That vector would be pass into a word count function and print out how many word are repeating.
for example:
count per word: age = 2 , belief = 1, best =1, it = 10
however i'm trying to come up with a function that loop to the same vector and print out the word that are repeated more than two time. In this case the word "it" is repeated more than two time.

```
map<string, int> get_word_count(const vector<string>& words) {
map<string, int> word_count{};

for (string word : words) {
    auto search = word_count.find(word);
    if (search == word_count.end()) {
        word_count[word] = 1;   // not found - add word with count of 1
    }
    else {
        word_count[word] += 1;  // found - increment count for word
    }
}
return word_count;
```

}

this is my snipet of code that check the many word that are repeated from the vector. However im struggle to figure out how to add a condition to check if the word are repeated twice or more than two time. I try to add a condition if word_count > 2, then print out the repeated word of twice. However it did not work.  I hope to hear from you guys hint, thank.

Comment: Just have another loop over elements in the map and print values when count is >= 2. And by the way you do not need to check if item in the map, just say `word_count[word]++` without condition.

Comment: So in this case, I would use : for(string word: words){ word_count[word]++ }? Sorry again since i'm still a bit confuse about map since we just learn it in class this week. @ Slava

Answer (score 2):

No need to check as a `std::map` automatically check if the entry exists or not. If not, it creates a new one, if yes, the value is handled correctly.

Simply loop over the `std::map` which holds the words vs. counts and use a condition as needed. See full example.

```
 int main()
 {   
    std::vector< std::string > words{ "belief","best","it","it","it" };

    std::map< std::string, int > counts;

    for ( const auto& s: words )
    {   
        counts[s]++;
    }   

    for ( const auto& p: counts )
    {   
        if ( p.second > 2 ) { std::cout << p.first << " repeats " << p.second << std::endl; }
    }   
}
```

Hint:

If you write `auto x: y` you get a copy of each element of y which is typically not what you want. If you write `const auto& x: y` you get a const reference to the element of your container, which is in your case much faster/efficient, as there is no need to create a copy. The compiler is maybe able to "see" that the copy is not needed and optimize it out, but it is more clear to the reader of the source code, what is intended!

Comment: Thank you for the tip! I will look more into it.

Comment: thank you, since im new to SO, i will definitely up-vote it.

Comment: @Verax11 At some point in the near future a green check mark should appear near the question score, allowing you to select an answer as your accepted answer. Future questioners are more likely to click on a question with an acknowledged answer. The ability to accept an answer is on a timer because, unfortunately, people have demonstrated a willingness to accept the first answer they are given without first trying it. If forced to wait, they may find flaws or better answers.

Answer (score -1):

first of all I really suggest you to explore documentation about C++ before coding,
your code is actually rewritable in this way

```
map<string, int> get_word_count(const vector<string>& words) {
    map<string, int> word_count{};

    for (string& word : words) {
        word_count[word] += 1;
    }
    return word_count;
}
```

This works because map::operator[] (like unordered_map::operator[]) doesn't work like map::at does (which throws a std::out_of_range exception if the key is not in the map). The difference is that operator[] returns a reference to the Value at the given key and if the key is not already in the map, it is inserted and default-initialized (in your case a int is value-initialized to 0).
[Operator[] on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at)

In order to add the "twice or more than twice" part you can modify your code by adding the condition in the for loop.

```
map<string, int> get_word_count(const vector<string>& words) {
    map<string, int> word_count{};

    for (string& word : words) {
        auto& map_ref = word_count[word];
        map_ref += 1;
        if(map_ref == 2){
        // Here goes your code
        }
    }
    return word_count;
}
```

If you're interested in how many times a word is repeated you shall scan again the map with a loop.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I will look more in depth to it. Thank you!.

Comment: just a quick question, how would I pass my vector in the main function with this function? Sorry again since i'm still new to map i'm having difficulty with it, modifying this code.

Comment: user4581301 is right and I'm going to change it,
you can easily do this in the main
`vector<string> myVector;`
then you fill it in some way and then
`auto word_count_map = get_word_count(myVector);`